# const-correctness for this and member functions

Tags: c++, c++11, this

assuming that I have a generic class A

```
class A {
  ...
  int a;                // a member
  void foo() const{...} // a member function qualified as const
  ...
};
```

this implies that if I declare an instance of `A` like `A k;` and then I call `k.foo();` the `this` pointer that is acting on/inside that call to `foo` is something of type `const A * const` .

Now I would like to know why the code in this [blog post](http://drj11.wordpress.com/2007/03/21/stupid-const-stupid-mutable-stupid-c/) works, especially about why this doesn't apply to global variables.

My explanation is about an hidden operation about pointer aliasing, like the `this` pointer being copied implicitly and during this copy the result is not `const` anymore ( for some reason ... ) but it's still a `this` pointer meaning that is a pointer to the same instance.

My question is about: what really `const` does if it's applied after the declaration of an interface for a member function ? Do you have a specific answer for the linked blog post ?

---

code from the blog

```
#include <iostream>

class counter {
public:
  int i;    
  counter();    
  int inspect() const;
  void increment();
};

counter sigma_inspect; // sigma_inspect is global

counter::counter() { i = 0; }

int counter::inspect() const {
  sigma_inspect.increment();
  return i;
}

void counter::increment() {
  ++i;
  return;
}

int main(void) {
  counter a; 
  std::cout << a.inspect() << "\n"; 
  std::cout << sigma_inspect.inspect() << "\n";
  std::cout << sigma_inspect.inspect() << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

---

Comment: Which exact part of the blog's code are you having trouble with?  Please just put the snippet here.

Comment: Please include the minimum amount of coded needed to understand the question without reading the blog post.

Comment: @JohnZwinck why a member function declared as `const` allows to modify a member value ? And pretty much everything related to how a `const` member functions is supposed to be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The call in the blog post is using `sigma_inspect` which is non-const and it is calling a non-const method on it instead of calling said method through the const `this` pointer. So what? The author seems to expect magic instead of the obvious of what he wrote. It's like having

```
T* t = ...;
const T* ct = t;
t->foo(); // foo() is not const, but hey,
          // I also have a const pointer now (ct),
          // so why can I still use this???
```

Generally, if someone calls C++ stupid it tells you more about the author instead of the language :)

Comment: I wasn't trying to flame a discussion, but that code was interesting at first sight, I admit that I'm not that used to think about global variables, I forgot to think about the most obvious behaviour that can lead to a function call. So for `T` a this pointer for a member function declared as const is `const T * const` ?

Comment: @user2485710 Yes, the `this` pointer of a `const` method does *not* allow you to call non-const member functions through it. But if you use a different, non-const pointer/reference to the same object, you are of course allowed to call non-const member functions through those pointers/references.